# Get Response from 3rd party API .NET CORE

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I have a code like:

```
[HttpPost("ConsumeApiKavling")]
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> ConsumeApiKavling([FromBody] Kavlings model)
    {
        string apiBaseUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("WebAPIBaseUrl");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var Response = await client.PostAsync(apiBaseUrl, content);
        return Response.StatusCode;
    }
```

So when I run, the `apiBaseUrl` will send a response something like:

```
{
  KavlingID: '4x',
  Status: 'OK'
}
```

From that response, how can I get it? I mean, I want to save it to my table in the database.
Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `Response.Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the approach you want to take, you could use the following workflow:

1. Create the Model that will hold the API response
2. (Optional): Create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) or ViewModel with the properties that you are going to pass to your data access service/database
3. Read the body content from the API response with:

   ```
   string jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   ```
4. Deserialize the returned JSON object (read JSON into your .NET object)

   ```
   var responseModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseModel>(jsonResult);
   ```
5. (Optional): Map your Model to your DTO and pass it over to the data access service

NOTE: You could use the JsonSerializerOptions if you want some extra options for your JSON deserialization

Comment: You might want to change your answer to use JSON.NET rather than System.Text.Json.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So how can I change the `return` ? Just leave it like that?

Comment: also it says, when I declare `var responseModel` , the jsonResult showing redline.. Which is cannot convert to string to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.